# Как работает ncurses?

Tags: c, консоль, ncurses, curses

При инициализации окна, используя библиотеку ncurses — initscr(), — будто бы создаётся отдельная область. То есть стирается текст терминала, сбрасывается прокрутка и мы теперь пишем в "чистом" окне. Потом, при выходе, данные восстанавливаются. Уж навряд ли библиотека сохраняет и загружает весь текст. И, думается мне, реализовано это при помощи управляющих последовательностей терминала. Отпишитесь, пожалуйста, кто знает, как такое сделать: нет желания копаться в исходниках.

Comment: Не знаю, как сделано в ncurses, а в https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797 пишут -- `Common Private Modes
These are some examples of private modes, which are not defined by the specification, but are implemented in most terminals....   ESC[?47h  save screen ... ESC[?47l  restore screen`  (найдено в гугле по запросу `terminal escape sequence`)

Comment: О, Вы меня просто спасли! Нижайше кланяюсь!

Comment: Пытаюсь разобраться, как сделать комментарий ответом. Извините неопытность 

Comment: Сейчас перенесу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, как сделано в ncurses, а в [gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797) пишут:

> Common Private Modes
>
> These are some examples of private modes, which are not defined by the
> specification, but are implemented in most terminals ...
>
> ESC[?47h  save screen
> ESC[?47l   restore screen

(найдено в гугле по запросу terminal escape sequence)